# LINQ find closest coordinates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a database full of coordinates (x,y), and i wish to find the coordinates closest to a point.  (there can be multiple closest to this point)

I've written this 2 LINQ's, but there must be a smarte way, than going through the database two times:

```
var closestDistance = _context.Coordinates.Min(x =>
                          Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((point.coordX - x.CoordX), 2) +
                                    Math.Pow((point.coordY- x.CoordY), 2)));
var closest = _context.Coordinates.Where(x=> closestDistance ==
                          Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((point.coordX - x.CoordX), 2) +
                                    Math.Pow((point.coordY - x.CoordY), 2)));
```

How can i optimize this?

Comment: BTW you don't need to square root the values if you just want to find the closest (rather than the actual distance).

Comment: Can you not use a kd tree?

Comment: @Matthew I honestly dont know... Math.Pow would be pretty easy to get around.. If EF cant translate, my question will still be, how can i achieve my wanted result with only one full table scan and not 2 as now

Comment: @VC 74. I would rather not have to load this into memory as the tables contains alot of data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of a group by. Furthermore, you don't have to calculate the square root. You could just use the sum of the squares of the corresponding differences.

Using the `GroupBy`, you build a sequence of groups, whose key is the distance of the points of each group from the point you are interested in. Then you make an `OrderBy` of the groups based on the key's value. Last you pick the first group. This contains the points you are looking for.

```
var closest = _context.Coordinates
                      .GroupBy(x => Math.Pow((point.coordX - x.CoordX), 2) + Math.Pow((point.WinningCoordY - x.CoordY), 2))
                      .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                      .First();
```

Answer (score 8):

1. You can not calc Math.Sqrt - it does not matter (3 > 2 and 3*3 > 2*2)
2. You can sort by dist and take first:

---

```
var closest = _context.Coordinates.OrderBy(x =>
               Math.Pow((point.coordX - x.CoordX), 2) + Math.Pow((point.WinningCoordY - x.CoordY), 2))
             .First();
```

3. Also, replace Math.Pow with multiplication - it will be much faster:

---

```
var closest = _context.Coordinates.OrderBy(x =>
               (point.coordX - x.CoordX) * (point.coordX - x.CoordX) + (point.WinningCoordY - x.CoordY) * (point.WinningCoordY - x.CoordY))
             .First();
```

Comment: You got some pretty good points. Thanks for the help. I need more than just the first, but if i make a groupBy as Christos suggested, i think i got what i needed

Comment: @sirius I inattentively read your question and missed a requirement about multiple points, so, I can improve my answer with grouping. but I advice you to replace Math.Pow